# TS 3.7 beta - Assertion signatures not narrowing down properties used in an optional-chain

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the new TypeScript 3.7 optional chaining in combination with assert signatures.

Based on my knowledge of optional chaining I'd expect `x` to always be non-null if `x?.y` is non-null.
Unfortunately the latest TypeScript 3.7 nightly doesn't seem to reflect this:

```js
declare function assertNonNull<T>(x: T | null): asserts x is T;
declare const x: { y: T | null } | null;

assertNonNull(x?.y);
doSomething(x.y); // Error: this.prop is possibly 'null'

assertNonNull(x);
doSomething(x.y); // No error, y is already correctly narrowed down to T
```

Why does TypeScript not narrow down the type of `x` to `T` after the assertion when used in a optional chain?

Edit: I discovered this happens with regular type guards too.

Comment: As far as I know type guards, and probably custom assertions would only impact the type of `x.y` the type of `x` would remain the same after any guard. This just seems an extension of that behavior.. But since we are talking about nightly builds maybe file an issue on GH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue as of TS 3.8.3 (although it could've been fixed earlier).